# How to split a column with json string into their own columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a dataframe like (with one example row):

```
raw_data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'FRANK', 'attributes': '{"deleted": false, "rejected": true, "handled": true, "order": "37"}'}]
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

I would like to break the json in the attributes column into their own columns with each of their values so that the resulting dataframe looks like:

```
new_data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'FRANK', 'deleted': 'false', 'rejected': 'true', 'handled': 'true', 'order': 37}]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

Is there a way I can break up the json to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: How did you end up with `raw_df`? Maybe [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) can help. Also [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Comment: This is an example line from a csv that I am reading using ```pd.read_csv```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your json string with `json.loads` then use `pd.json_normalize` to convert as dataframe:

> You are NaN values in attributes column
>
> It gives back 66 for the entire column
>
> Am i not able to split the json if some of the rows in that column are NaN?

To fix `NaN` values, you can replace `NaN` by empty dict string `'{}'`

```
import json

attr_df = pd.json_normalize(raw_df.pop('attributes').fillna('{}').map(json.loads))
new_df = pd.concat([raw_df, attr_df], axis=1)
print(new_df)

# Output
   id   name  deleted  rejected  handled order
0   1  FRANK    False      True     True    37
```

Comment: I am getting this error ```TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float``` do I have to convert the column to a string somehow? My raw data is formatted in this way ```raw_data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'FRANK', 'attributes': '{\n "deleted": false,\n "rejected": true,\n "handled": true,\n "order": "37"}'}]``` and then i turned it into a dataframe using ```pd.DataFrame(raw_data)```

Comment: I think you are `NaN` values in `attributes` column. What is the output of `print(df['attributes'].isna().sum())`?

Comment: Ah yes it gives back 66 for the entire column

Comment: Am i not able to split the json if some of the rows in that column are NaN?

Comment: No you can't. A possible solution is to modify the code with `attr_df = pd.json_normalize(raw_df.pop('attributes').fillna('{}').map(json.loads))`: replace nan by empty string dict.